# AngularJS/Bootstrap: How to fix accordion-heading on the top while scrolling

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have directive having a template of an `angularjs` `accordion` list as follows, where each `accordion-body` section has a long content. So, when I expand an item in the list and scroll down to view all the content, the item header goes above the view port. I wanted to fix the header (`accordion-heading`) on the top while I am scrolling down to it's content. How can we achieve that?

Sample Code:

**list.html**

```
<accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="myObject in someArray"  is-open="myObject.isOpen">
        <accordion-heading ng-click="myObject.isOpen = !myObject.isOpen">
            <div >
                {{myObject.title}}
            </div>
        </accordion-heading>
        <accordion-body>
            <div>
                {{myObject.longContent}}
            </div>
        </accordion-body>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

**list.js**

```
angular.module('app.directives')
    .directive('listDirective', function () {

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: '=',
            templateUrl: "list.html",
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attr)  {

            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it:

Look for the panel (div) with the current scroll (it includes the accordion header) and set:

```
 overflow-y: hidden
```

Look for the panel (div) you want to have the scroll and set:

```
max-height: 400px     
overflow-y: auto
```

Change the max-height to the value that works for you.
Hope this help. It worked for me.

Here how it looks:
[image]